# Why does Equals(object) win over Equals(T) when using an inherited object in Hashset or other Collections?

Tags: c#, inheritance, iequatable

I am aware of the fact that I always have to override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` when implementing `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)`.

However, I don't understand, why in some situations the `Equals(object)` wins over the generic `Equals(T)`.

For example why is the following happening? If I declare `IEquatable<T>` for an interface and implement a concrete type `X` for it, the general `Equals(object)` is called by a `Hashset<X>` when comparing items of those type against each other. In all other situations where at least one of the sides is cast to the Interface, the correct `Equals(T)` is called.

Here's a code sample to demonstrate:

```
public interface IPerson : IEquatable<IPerson> { }

//Simple example implementation of Equals (returns always true)
class Person : IPerson
{
    public bool Equals(IPerson other)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

private static void doEqualityCompares()
{
    var t1 = new Person();

    var hst = new HashSet<Person>();
    var hsi = new HashSet<IPerson>();

    hst.Add(t1);
    hsi.Add(t1);

    //Direct comparison
    t1.Equals(t1);                  //IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)

    hst.Contains(t1);               //Equals(object) --> why? both sides inherit of IPerson...
    hst.Contains((IPerson)t1);      //IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)

    hsi.Contains(t1);               //IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)
    hsi.Contains((IPerson)t1);      //IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `hst.Contains((IPerson)t1);` fail to compile?

Comment: @Dennis_E See the second half of my answer.

Comment: @Dennis_E: that's not `HashSet<T>.Contains` but `Enumerable.Contains` which accepts the interface. So this is the slow version that enumerates all elements and compares them with `Equals(IPerson other)` instead of using `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Ok, I did not think about that. I tried it on ideone.com and it failed to compile. But that's because I didn't add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Every time someone complains Java has more confusing behaviour than C# I should point them to this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` calls `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to get the default equality comparer when no comparer is provided.

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` determines if `T` implements`IEquatable<T>`.  If it does, it uses that, if not, it uses `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode`.

Your `Person` object implements `IEquatable<IPerson>` not `IEquatable<Person>`.

When you have a `HashSet<Person>` it ends up checking if `Person` is an `IEquatable<Person>`, which its not, so it uses the `object` methods.

When you have a `HashSet<IPerson>` it checks if `IPerson` is an `IEquatable<IPerson>`, which it is, so it uses those methods.

---

As for the remaining case, why does the line:

```
hst.Contains((IPerson)t1);
```

call the `IEquatable` `Equals` method even though its called on the `HashSet<Person>`.  Here you're calling `Contains` on a `HashSet<Person>` and passing in an `IPerson`.  `HashSet<Person>.Contains` requires the parameter to be a `Person`; an `IPerson` is not a valid argument.  However, a `HashSet<Person>` is also an `IEnumerable<Person>`, and since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, that means it can be treated as an `IEnumerable<IPerson>`, which has a `Contains` extension method (through LINQ) which accepts an `IPerson` as a parameter.

`IEnumerable.Contains` also uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to get its equality comparer when none is provided.  In the case of this method call we're actually calling `Contains` on an `IEnumerable<IPerson>`, which means `EqualityComparer<IPerson>.Default` is checking to see if `IPerson` is an `IEquatable<IPerson>`, which it is, so that `Equals` method is called.

Comment: I see - so the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` can actually only get the `Equals(T)` method if it is exactly of the type T - it wouldn't be able to get it of a type T' which inherited of T. I thought there was polymorphism in the game but obviously I was completely wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It should be noted that they have chosen *not* to make `IEquatable<T>` contravariant in its type argument `T`. If they had made `IEquatable<>` contravariant (would have been `IEquatable<in T>`), something that was an `IEquatable<IPerson>` would implicitly have been an `IEquatable<Person>` as well. However, I guess making it contravariant would have led to even worse problems (than what we already have) when people derive from classes that implement `IEquatable<>`. ***Edit:*** Ah, I see supercat already mentioned this in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although `IComparable<in T>` is contravariant with respect to `T`, such that any type which implements `IComparable<Person>` would automatically be considered an implementation of `IComparable<IPerson>`, the type `IEquatable<T>` is intended for use with sealed types, especially structures.  The requirement that `Object.GetHashCode()` be consistent with both `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` and `Object.Equals(Object)` generally implies that the latter two methods should behave identically, which in turn implies that one of them should chain to the other.  While there is a large performance difference between passing a struct directly to an `IEquatable<T>` implementation of the proper type, compared with constructing a instance of the structure's boxed-heap-object type and having an `Equals(Object)` implementation copy the structure data out of that, no such performance different exists with reference types.  If `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` and `Equals(Object)` are going to be equivalent and `T` is an inheritable reference type, there's no meaningful difference between:

```
bool Equals(MyType obj)
{
  MyType other = obj as MyType;
  if (other==null || other.GetType() != typeof(this))
    return false;
  ... test whether other matches this
}

bool Equals(MyType other)
{
  if (other==null || other.GetType() != typeof(this))
    return false;
  ... test whether other matches this
}
```

The latter could save one typecast, but that's unlikely to make a sufficient performance difference to justify having two methods.